# Chart plug-in module for MS Access

Tags: ms-access, plugins, charts

I have been having trouble with the built in Access charts, [see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/888184/). Now I am looking for alternatives to the MSCharts that plugin to Access. My initial search on google turned up only noise.

It doesn't have to be open source and it can cost real money.